# Is the sum of these vectors zero or not?

Tags: vectors

**Question:**

ABCD is a quadrilateral. O is the point of intersection of lines joining the mid points of AB,CD,AD and BC, i.e. P,Q,R,S show that $ \vec{OP}+\vec{QO}+\vec{RO}+\vec{OS}=\vec{0}.$

**My attempt:-**
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\vec{OP}+\vec{OQ}+\vec{OR}+\vec{OS}=\vec{0}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. It cannot be $\vec 0$, unless $B=D$.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that $PRQS$ is a parallelogram and you'll see that the Left Side it's $$\vec{QS}+\vec{QR}+\vec{RP}+\vec{RQ}=\vec{QP}+\vec{RS},$$ which is not $\vec{0}$.

Comment: What's LS here?

Comment: @Iti Shree It's Left Side

Comment: Okay thanks for clearing up.